# How to swap date and month digits in excel

Tags: excel, date, format

I have a date format of mm-dd-yyyy (03-12-2018). Excel reads it as 3rd December 2018. The actual date is 3rd March 2018, I want to convert it into 12th March 2018 in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Let's assume our data is in cell B2 and it reads 03-12-2018 i.e 3rd December 2018 I have tried =Date(right(B2,4),mid(B2,4,2),left(B2,2)). It gives 12-02-3440 as output due to excel date-time code.

Comment: Your example is not that of swapping date and month; rather it is an example of writing the day value into both the month and day fields. Which do you want?

Comment: Once you figure out what you want to do, you can convert using the `DATE`, `DAY` & `MONTH` functions.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i want it as 12th March 2018

Comment: I have tried it, its not working.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you have tried, and explain what you mean by *not working*

Comment: Let's assume our data is in cell B2 and it reads 03-12-2018 i.e 3rd December 2018   I have tried =Date(right(B2,4),mid(B2,4,2),left(B2,2)). It gives 12-02-3440 as output due to excel date-time code.

Comment: That indicates that your date in `B2` is not a string, but is a real Excel date.  So string functions will not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This most likely will not solve your underlying problem, but to swap month-day in an Excel date, you can use:

```
=DATE(YEAR(B2),DAY(B2),MONTH(B2))
```

Then format the cell to show whatever date format you want.

However, if your underlying problem stems from opening a csv or txt file, you'll need to change that method to an import method to sort out your various date issues.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:
convert both wrong date and wrong text(likely also happen to you that some dates are not recognized as date but as text)

This is convert a `DD/MM/YYYY` into `MM/DD/YYYY` format regardless whether original format seen as date or text.

```
=DATE(RIGHT(TEXT(Cell,"MM/DD/YYYY"),4),MID(TEXT(Cell,"MM/DD/YYYY"),4,2),LEFT(TEXT(Cell,"MM/DD/YYYY"),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that what you want to say is that the date in the cell is '03-12-2018' which is read by the Excel as 3rd December 2018 but the actual date is 12th March 2018.

So basically it's a mm-dd-yy format but Excel is reading it as dd-mm-yy format. In that case even if you will try to change the format then excel will think that mm is dd and so on and will swap it accordingly.

For this I found a workaround on the internet and it worked for me as well. You can select the Text to Column option from the Data ribbon and from there select Delimeter as other and leave it as blank, in the next option select the data type as Date and format in which the existing date already is. [image: From here.]

In case if Excel fails to identify the date correctly then you need to separate your dates via delimiter '-' and then re-join the dates by swapping cells with '/' or '-'.

I hope this helps.